# How to prove that this set is an ellipsoid?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, ellipsoids

Assuming that matrix $Q$ is positive definite, how can we show that the following set is an ellipsoid?

$$\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x^TQ^{-1}x + 2 q^T x \leq r \}$$

where $q \in \mathbb R^n$. I can show it is an ellipsoid for the case $q = 0_n$, but not for the case $q \neq 0_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: multiply the terms in the expression 
$$
(x+Qq)^TQ^{-1}(x+Qq),
$$
compare with the given one and try to rewrite it as an ellipsoid in the variable $z=x+Qq$.

What you get is

> the ellipsoid centered at $Qq$: $z^TQ^{-1}z=x^TQ^{-1}x+2q^Tx+q^TQq\le r+q^TQq=\rho$ (a constant).

Comment: This opens as $$x^TQ^{-1}x+x^Tq+q^TQ^TQ^{-1}x+q^TQ^Tq$$ whats next? I think $Q^TQ^{-1}$ is identity matrix ($I$)?

Comment: @FrankMoses Right, $Q=Q^T$ (and $x^Tq=q^Tx$). Now how can you bound it if the first three terms are $\le r$?

Comment: I do not have any clue. Please add some steps which you are talking about

Comment: @FrankMoses Add as a spoiler.